# Can I bin deploy and MVC4 for .NET 4 where I have an MVC3 app running?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC3 app on a shared hosting server and would like to upgrade this project by creating a new MVC4 project and copying my content over. Will the required dependencies be publish when I do a file system publish of the MVC4 app, or are there GAC etc. requirements on the server? I will be using .NET 4 which I am already using fine on the hosting server.

Comment: You should be able to do it without any issues.

Comment: @PieterGermishuys At least Afrihost support has always been good for me with these things. I'll give it a trial later this week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to to an MVC4 Beta bin deploy with no problem to a server with only MVC3 installed.  I followed [Phil Haack's guide](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) for doing this (it was written for MVC3 but the steps are the same).

All you have to do is right-click on the project and select "Add Deployable Assemblies".  This also allowed our unit test assemblies to run just fine, so there was no need to install the beta on our continuous integration server.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx