# Requirements for running ASP.Net MVC 2 and MVC 4 side by side

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a hard time finding the information after searching.  We have a brand new server for our sites.  One is a MVC 2 site, and the other is a MVC 4 site.  I want to install just the bare requirements for these two sites.

Is the MVC framework included in certain versions of .Net?  The installers on the MVC site look like they're all for development, and I don't want any of the tools installed, just what's required for the sites to run.

Comment: upgrade your mvc2 app to mvc4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installers for either MVC 2 or 4 do have the tooling included, but it will only be installed when you have Visual Studio installed on a given machine. If it's just a server then you should feel free to use those installers.

Comment: Should both ASP.NET MVC 2 and MVC 4 be installed using the installer? If I understand correctly, both can be installed side by side, but you'll need to specify which assembly you're targeting in the web.config. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Installing .NET 4 is all you need. Then make sure the DLLs are copied during deployment, i.e. use [bin deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234130/can-i-bin-deploy-and-mvc4-for-net-4-where-i-have-an-mvc3-app-running) for the ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

Comment: It currently has .NET 4.5 installed, does that include .NET 4 or do I need to install that as well?

Comment: .NET 4.5 is fine, you need at least .NET 4 for ASP.NET MVC 4. You'll only need .NET 4.5 if your application was built using .NET 4.5, i.e. it uses .NET 4.5 assemblies. .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 are on the same runtime but have additional/different DLLs.