# Hosting an asp.net mvc site

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, hosting

I have an asp,net MVC 4 project. I chose a hosting company www.somee.com for a quick test. What I did was uploading a zip file and unzipped it.
When I opened the url, I got the error.

```
   IIS 8.0 Detailed error

   HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
   The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
   Most likely causes:

   A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

   Things you can try:

   If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
   Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager.
    Open IIS Manager.
    In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
    On the Directory Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable.
    Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

    Detailed Error Information:
    Module     DirectoryListingModule
    Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
    Handler    StaticFile
    Error Code     0x00000000
    Requested URL      http://xxxx.somee.com:80/
    Physical Path      d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\username\www.xxxx.somee.com
    Logon Method       Anonymous
    Logon User     Anonymous
```

Does it meant I should try on my local IIS or server IIS? But I have no control on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is where I'd start

1. Verify that MVC is a feature that your host even offers. Your site
   won't work otherwise and you could get an error like this as routing
   will fail
2. Contact support for your host. Any host I've used in the past has
   been very helpful with problems like this and they have more access
   to figure out what is going wrong

Here is some information in case you need to bin deploy:

[Can I bin deploy and MVC4 for .NET 4 where I have an MVC3 app running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234130/can-i-bin-deploy-and-mvc4-for-net-4-where-i-have-an-mvc3-app-running)

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Good Luck

Comment: MVC was designed to support bin-deploy, so it doesn't have to be installed on the server.

Comment: You're certainly correct, OP if the host doesn't support MVC then hopefully you're deploying the necessary MVC dll's.

Comment: Does your response to @CodeCaster mean that MVC will work even if the host does not directly support it?  Thanks.

Comment: If the host doesn't support MVC then you have to include the necessary MVC dlls in your deploy package. It will still work, but you will have to specifically make sure to include the necessary files. I've updated my answer to include some links that might help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the website in what would be there IIS?

Try following the steps on here:

http://somee.com/DOKA/DoHelpTopics.aspx?docode=false&thnid=50